# Yii Framework 1.1.14 - AJAX request not allowed - 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, yii

I have seen many other questions related to this one, I have tried their solutions but it still does not work (same error), reason why I am opening this thread.

Elements: 
1 View --> Originates the AJAX request.
1 Controller --> Should handle the AJAX request and return an array.

View:

> ```
>   $(document).ready(function(){
>       $("button").click(function(){
>               $("#test").load("<? echo >Yii::app()-createUrl('test/ajax');?>");
>               });             
>
>   });
> ```

So when I clicked a button with an "id=test", it should go to the TestController and from the actionAjax return a simple array.

The problem I am having is that whenever I click the #test button a 403 Forbidden log is seen in the console (Google Chrome console, for instance).

In the TestController I have the following access rules:

> public function accessRules() {
>        return array(
>
> ```
>  array('allow',
>
>        'actions'=array('ajax'),
>
>        'users'=array('@'),
>
>  ),
>  );    }
> ```

And of course I do have an action called actionAjax.

Am I missing something here? Is there any rule that I should take into account?

Am I free to make any Ajax call (load, post..) in Yii or there is a convention / function that I should follow?

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Might be a typo but you are missing a > character from your array syntax. Should be 'users' => array('@'),

Comment: Thanks for checking on this one.

Actually, after adding the code to the question the ">" characters were gone, but I do have them correct.

I get: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work with this one:

> $.ajax({
>
> ```
>         url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('test/ajax');?>",
>
>         data:{},
>
>         type:"POST",
>
>         dataType:"html",
>
>         success:function(response){
>
>              $('#test').html(response);
>
>         },
>
>         error:function(){
>
>              alert("Failed request data from AJAX request");
>
>         }
>
>     });
> ```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing characters in your array syntax.

```
public function accessRules() {
return array(
array('allow',
   'actions'=>array('ajax'),
   'users'=>array('@'),
     ),
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for checking on this one.

Actually, after adding the code to the question the ">" characters were gone, but I do have them correct.

Any other suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Forbidden means that you have to add that rule in accessRules of your controller:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                'actions' => array('ajax'),
                'users' => array('@'),
            ),
            array('deny',
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

And take a look at your code because is full of typo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#test").load("<? echo Yii::app()->createUrl('test/ajax'); ?>");
    });             
});
```